# NetLogo: How can the heading of a turtle be passed onto another turtle within a radius?

Tags: netlogo

A turtle reaches a point and for a set amount of time, can relate it's heading to other turtles within it's range.

Pseudo code

```
if any? turtles within 5
[pass on heading to other turtle]
```

The other turtle I'm assuming would need a call to use this heading, so something like

Pseudo code

```
if has received heading?
set heading new heading
```

Also I need to reverse this heading, so that the turtle receiving the heading does not travel at this heading, but rather travels in the opposite direction i.e the direction the other turtle was travelling from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ask turtles in-radius 5 [
  set heading [ heading ] of myself
]
```

[`myself`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#myself), aka the worst named primitive in NetLogo, refers to the turtle doing the asking.